# Set Xcode bundle version to git hash

Tags: xcode, git

In Xcode, I want to set the project bundle version to the git hash, to create a unique link between a revision and a build.

(I have seen several postings about this that increase the build number for each build, but to me this seems excessive, and I would like to have a build number that testers can refer to when sender feedback).

I added the following as a Run Script in Build Phases:

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleVersion `git rev-parse --short HEAD`" *.plist
```

And then I read out the bundle version in the code with:

```
[[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleVersion"];
```

However, then the new revision number does not appear in the code until the *next* build. I assume this is because the plist file is already read by the compiler when my script is run.

Also, since the plist is changed with the revision string *after* committing to git, this causes an annoying diff in the project, so maybe I am not so smart after all.

An alternative would be to write the revision number to a text file (build.txt) which is ignored by git. But I would still like the project build number to follow git as well.

Anyone know a brilliant way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://gist.github.com/966838 is a short bash script that meets Apple's requirement that [CFBundleVersion should be a monotonically increased string](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001431-102364).

Answer (score 8):

You will need to install `PlistBuddy` to use this method.

The method that I use is to set the script as the last build phase, and make the changes on the target build directory. In other words:

```
BUILD_NUMBER=`git rev-parse --short HEAD`
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleVersion $BUILD_NUMBER" "${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}"/"${INFOPLIST_PATH}"
```

So in the repo the value should be a dummy value like 0, and it will get overwritten everytime. This does mean that the current build number will only be available after you build.

Answer (score 4):

There have been quite a few ways to do this.

I used to run a post build script to inject the sha into the bundle:

https://gist.github.com/208825

But a more modern method is on the Cocoa is my Girlfriend blog http://www.cimgf.com/2011/02/20/revisiting-git-tags-and-building/

Comment: Running this last in the build phases, I get: `private method sub! called for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)`

Comment: For those wondering how to create the Shell Script Target — required by these scripts — in the new Xcode: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9088985

Comment: @Abizern you said you used to use this script what do you do now instead?

Comment: @Paul.s I don't use any of them - They don't work with the App Store requirement of a monotonically increasing build number. Now I just increment the version in my distribution builds and add that version as a tag to the repository so I know the state of the code for that version number.

Comment: @Abizern is there any technical reason why you didn't just use a custom key?

Comment: @Abizern thanks for your help, I might experiment with adding the commit hash programatically then there is no way of me forgetting to do it manually - which I tend to do more often than not with manual processes.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a [much shorter script](http://a2n-work.blogspot.com/2012/04/git-hooks-xcode-version.html) for this. Bash can accomplish the task; no need for other interpreters.