# How do you create a Shell Script target in Xcode 4.2?

Tags: objective-c, shell, xcode4, xcode4.2

I was wondering if anyone knew with XCode 4.1 how to create a shell script. The option for that doesn't exist, but it might be called something else in the latest version.
Ta

Comment: Do you need to run this script alone or this should be run after or before a build of particular target?

Comment: Should be before (but answered below).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

1. Select your project in the navigator
2. Click "Add Target" - Choose "Aggregate" for an empty Target
3. Add Build Phase -> Add Run Script
4. Click Build Phases and edit the Run Script Phase

Comment: why do i keep on bumping into you on SO? :)

Comment: @abbood probably because i spend too much time here :)

Comment: actually i came across this question there is this library i'm using [mailcore2](https://github.com/MailCore/mailcore2) that *always* executes this shell script everytime i build it.. I wanna shut it off.. I'll let you know if I get stuck though :p

Comment: An alternative to using a Run Script is to edit the Scheme and under "Run" > "Info" select `/usr/bin/sh` as the executable and under "Run" > "Arguments" select the script in "Arguments Passed On Launch" that you wish to run. This way you'll get the output in Xcode's console. In my project, I do this to run a Ruby script using `/usr/bin/ruby` as the executable and `$(PROJECT_DIR)/myscript.rb` as the argument.

Comment: I'm currently facing the same problem right now, difference is, there is no Aggregate option on Target in xcode 9.4.1. Can you please help me? Thanks