# How can I include the git commit hash in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have an application, which people can report bugs directly from it, but I'd like for the user to be able to submit what git hash the application was built on.  Does Xcode expose a #define which will include this information or would I have to include it in some custom build script?

Comment: This will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8192921/set-xcode-bundle-version-to-git-hash

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I've written an implementation based on the answer cited by gagarwal.  I added this build script to my build phases before the compilation phase:

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :GIT_COMMIT_HASH `git rev-parse HEAD`" "${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}"/"${INFOPLIST_PATH}"
```

In my code I reference it by calling:

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary][@"GIT_COMMIT_HASH"];
```

And voila, your last commit hash value is available at run-time!

Comment: I'm getting `Set: Entry, ":GIT_COMMIT_HASH", Does Not Exist`

Comment: @DavidH you have to have the entry already in your info plist, so before being built I have `<key>GIT_COMMIT_HASH</key><string></string>` in the plist and it get's populated at build time.

Comment: I added the script before the Compilation step and added the GIT_COMMIT_HASH key to my info.plist, but I'm still getting that error. Is there anything else I need to do?

Comment: I moved the script to the ned instead of before the compilation step and it's working fine now.

Comment: looks like for XCode 7 this is not working anymore. Fixed it with that: /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :GIT_COMMIT_HASH `git rev-parse HEAD`" "${PROJECT_DIR}/${INFOPLIST_FILE}"

Comment: I've added this script to Build-Phases -> run scripts, and I've added the entry GIT_COMMIT_HASH at the plist, and when I run this code the value I get is git rev-parse HEAD instead the real commit hash. What else should I define ?

Comment: Important thing is to add the script in "Build Phases" AFTER the "copy bundle resources" phase.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with builds for App Store, Apple says the build number must be indeed a number (increasing with each build within the same version).

Comment: @iosdude Use the GIT commit count instead. `git rev-list HEAD --count` The hash is to be used other than the build number to point to the exact commit.

Comment: @Roee84 You must have missed the "left quote" while copying the script from the above comment.

Comment: @RyanDignard updated code for swift `if  let gitHashCode = Bundle.main.infoDictionary!["GIT_COMMIT_HASH"]{
      print(gitHashCode)
    }`

Answer (score 5):

## Xcode 12+ solution

*Note:* You could avoid manual modification of `Info.plist`. Simply do following steps:

1. Add `New run script phase`
2. Insert the script:

```bash
INFO_PLIST="${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}"/"${INFOPLIST_PATH}"

# Query and save the value; suppress any error message, if key not found.
value=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c 'print :GitCommitHash' "${INFO_PLIST}" 2>/dev/null)

# Check if value is empty
if [ -z "$value" ] 
then
   /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Add :GitCommitHash string" "${INFO_PLIST}"
fi

/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :GitCommitHash `git rev-parse --short HEAD`" "${INFO_PLIST}"
```

3. Add `$BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR/$INFOPLIST_PATH` and `$TARGET_BUILD_DIR/$INFOPLIST_PATH` to `Input Files` property (**IMPORTANT!**)
4. Ensure that the phase goes after `Copy Bundle Resources` phase

Now you can get access to commit hash:

```swift
extension Bundle {
  var commitHash: String? {
    infoDictionary?["GitCommitHash"] as? String
  }
}

print(Bundle.main.commitHash ?? "undefined")
```

[image: Xcode build phases tab]

Answer (score 2):

This wasn't working for me on Xcode 12.  I placed the following in the Build Phases step as mentioned above after putting `GIT_COMMIT_HASH` in the `Info.plist` file:

```
COMMIT_HASH=`git rev-parse --short HEAD`
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :GIT_COMMIT_HASH $COMMIT_HASH" "${INFOPLIST_FILE}"
```

Then you can access it in Swift with:

```
Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "GIT_COMMIT_HASH")
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Add in your target's info.plist GIT_COMMIT_HASH key
   [image]
2. Build phases before the compilation phase:

/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :GIT_COMMIT_HASH '`git rev-parse --short HEAD'`" "${PROJECT_DIR}/${INFOPLIST_FILE}"